# What is the definition of $comp: Hom_{\mathcal{C}}\times_{Ob(\mathcal{C})}Hom_{\mathcal{C}} \rightarrow Hom_{\mathcal{C}}$?

Tags: category-theory

In "Category Theory for the Sciences", Spivak defines a category $\mathcal{C}$ as a sequence $(\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C}), \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}, dom, cod, ids, comp)$ where

- $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set;
- $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}$ is a set, and $dom, cod: \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}} \rightarrow\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ are functions;
- $ids:\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}$ is a function;
- and $comp$ is a function depicted in the commutative diagram below.

[image]

I have a hard time to understand how $comp$ acts here. Here is my understanding of this function. Starting from its domain, we have a fiber product

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}\times_{\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})}\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}} := \{(h, o, h')\mid dom(h) = o = cod(h')\},$$

for some arrows $h,h'\in Hom_{\mathcal{C}}$ and an object $o\in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$. So, $comp$ is supposed to operate on an instance $(h, o, h')$. But, $comp$ is not actually defined. Naive guesses $h\circ h'(o)$ and $h'\circ h(o)$ simply fail because $o$ may not be passed into $h$ or $h'$. So, can one explain what exactly the definition of $comp$ is here?

Comment: $comp$ represents composition; it sends $(h,o,h')$ to $h\circ h'$. The point of having $o$ and the equations relating it to $h$ and $h'$ is to ensure that $h\circ h'$ exists.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks for this clarification.

Comment: More generally, this is the definition of an [internal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category) in the category of sets. This terminology may be helpful in finding more detailed explanations.